# How can we use quadratic formula in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning to solve second order linear differential equations and in that my professor told me that we can write

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = Dy$$
And
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = D^2y $$

And using these two, we can solve any linear differential equations of second order.

Now in some cases, my professor even used the quadratic formula to get the "factors" for the differential and from there we can get the general solution to the equations.

But my concern is that how can we use quadratic formula here as $D^2$ is not equal to $(D)^2$ ?
And the quadratic formula was derived in my high schools using the [completing the square method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) which can't be applied here . I asked my professor but he just said that this thing works. He had no reason for it.

**So how can we use the quadratic formula to solve differential equations?**

Comment: In what sense are you worried that $D^2\neq (D)^2$? It's true that $(y')^2\neq y''$, but the claim here is rather that $y''=(y')'$ (i.e., taking the second derivative is the same as taking the first derivative twice).

Comment: Any linear differential equations of second order **with constant coefficients**, right?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark Yeah sorry i didn't mention that